# how to set tablet screen orientation locked before 4.3?

Tags: android, orientation, tablet, android-4.3-jelly-bean, locked

I have been developing tablet and mobile app.

Recently I encountered tablet orientation is not settled properly. 
I have used setRequestedOrientation in onCreate. 
If I set this, then in some activities, screen orientation will be changed in start time.
As a result, onConfigurationChanged called immediately after onCreate method.

After android version 4.3, I can set "locked" in AndroidManifest. So this issue is not happen.
But this property is not work below 4.3.

Additionally, I can't set orientation in AndroidManifest because of mobile version.

Comment: How about using *android:configChanges="orientation"* of the <activity> element in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I already use android:configChanges="orientation" to not call onCreate twice. Do you have an any idea? @hata